# Google Cloud SQL External IP not static?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I've got a micro instance of a Postgresql database on Google Cloud SQL, but the external IP seems to change occasionally. I've seen no documentation that says this is going to happen. It's only inconvenient while developing, but I need to understand how to make sure it won't happen when I want to go live with a larger instance. Any info appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inferring when you say "External IP" you are referring to the Public IP. The Public IP assigned to your instance will not change unless you disable the Public IP and enable it again. You can read the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip) to know more, it says:

> When you disable public IP for an instance, you release its IPv4
>   address. If you later reenable public IP for this instance, it will
>   get a different IPv4 address, and all applications that use the public
>   IP address to connect to this instance must be modified.

Have an eye on your instance and double check that you are not unintentionally disabling the public IP.